# Transforming `PCollection` with many elements into a single element

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to convert a `PCollection`, that has many elements, into a `PCollection` that has one element. Basically, I want to go from:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

to:

`[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`

so that I can work with the entire `PCollection` in a `DoFn`.

I've tried `CombineGlobally(lamdba x: x)`, but only a portion of elements get combined into an array at a time, giving me the following result:

```py
[1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Or something to that effect.

This is my relevant portion of my script that I'm trying to run:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
raw_input = range(1024)
def run_test():
    with TestPipeline() as test_pl:
        input = test_pl | "Create" >> beam.Create(raw_input)
        def combine(x):
            print(x)
            return x
        
        (
            input
            | "Global aggregation" >> beam.CombineGlobally(combine)
        )
        pl.run()

run_test()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a pretty painless way to do this, which I missed in the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/combineglobally/):

> The more general way to combine elements, and the most flexible, is
> with a class that inherits from CombineFn.
>
> CombineFn.create_accumulator(): This creates an empty accumulator. For
> example, an empty accumulator for a sum would be 0, while an empty
> accumulator for a product (multiplication) would be 1.
>
> CombineFn.add_input(): Called once per element. Takes an accumulator
> and an input element, combines them and returns the updated
> accumulator.
>
> CombineFn.merge_accumulators(): Multiple accumulators could be
> processed in parallel, so this function helps merging them into a
> single accumulator.
>
> CombineFn.extract_output(): It allows to do additional calculations
> before extracting a result.

I suppose supplying a lambda function that simply passes its argument to the "vanilla" `CombineGlobally` wouldn't do what I expected initially. That functionality has to be specified by me (although I still think it's weird this isn't built into the API).

You can find more about subclassing `CombineFn` [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.CombineFn), which I found very helpful:

> A CombineFn specifies how multiple values in all or part of a
> PCollection can be merged into a single value—essentially providing
> the same kind of information as the arguments to the Python “reduce”
> builtin (except for the input argument, which is an instance of
> CombineFnProcessContext). The combining process proceeds as follows:
>
> 1. Input values are partitioned into one or more batches.
> 2. For each batch, the create_accumulator method is invoked to create a fresh initial “accumulator” value representing the combination of
>    zero values.
> 3. For each input value in the batch, the add_input method is invoked to combine more values with the accumulator for that batch.
> 4. The merge_accumulators method is invoked to combine accumulators from separate batches into a single combined output accumulator value,
>    once all of the accumulators have had all the input value in their
>    batches added to them. This operation is invoked repeatedly, until
>    there is only one accumulator value left.
> 5. The extract_output operation is invoked on the final accumulator to get the output value. Note: If this CombineFn is used with a transform
>    that has defaults, apply will be called with an empty list at
>    expansion time to get the default value.

So, by subclassing `CombineFn`, I wrote this simple implementation, `Aggregated`, that does exactly what I want:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
raw_input = range(1024)


class Aggregated(beam.CombineFn):
    def create_accumulator(self):
        return []
    
    def add_input(self, accumulator, element):
        accumulator.append(element)
        return accumulator
    
    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        merged = []
        for a in accumulators:
            for item in a:
                merged.append(item)
        return merged
    
    def extract_output(self, accumulator):
        return accumulator


def run_test():
    with TestPipeline() as test_pl:
        input = test_pl | "Create" >> beam.Create(raw_input)
        (
            input
            | "Global aggregation" >> beam.CombineGlobally(Aggregated())
            | "print" >> beam.Map(print)
        )
        pl.run()

run_test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish what you want with [side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs), e.g.

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    pcoll = ...
    (p
     # Create a PCollection with a single element.
     | beam.Create([None])
     # This will process the singleton exactly once,
     # with the entirity of pcoll passed in as a second argument as a list.
     | beam.Map(
        lambda _, pcoll_as_side: ...consume pcoll_as_side here...,
        pcoll_as_side=beam.pvalue.AsList(pcoll))
```